# How to get difference amount with in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I need help in writing oracle query.
I have a data like as shown in the attached image.

There in the image i have 3 columns like `serno`,`accorder`,`balance`.

i want to derive another column called difference which derivation is first two rows of sum of balance - next two rows sum of balance like that for all rows i need to get the difference.

For example as shown in the image differnce should be calculated as difference of first two rows balance data - next two rows of balance data i.e (43801 + 43801) - (103397.25+103397.25)

[image: Image with data]

Comment: can you illustrate calculated values for each row of your sample data? is the same calculated balanced data will appear on all 4 rows ?

Comment: Why are the rows duplicated? Do you only want the difference calculated within each `serno`, so only the second pair of rows will get a value in your example? (Also please put your data in the question as formatted text, not as an image).

Comment: And should the first two rows both show -59596.25 or -119192.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try using case statement as follow

```
Select serNo,
    ( SUM(CASE accorder_
        when  1 then balance
        else 0 end)
      - SUM(case.accorder_
        when 2 then balance
        else 0 end)) as finalAmount
    from table name
    group by serNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [analytic `lead()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions086.htm) to look at related rows and calculate the difference; assuming you want the difference only between rows within the same `serno` and the 'next' rows are defined by `accorder`:

```
select serno, accorder, balance,
  balance - lead(balance, 2)
    over (partition by serno order by accorder) as diff
from t42
order by serno, accorder;

     SERNO   ACCORDER    BALANCE       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1      43801  -59596.25 
         1          1      43801  -59596.25 
         1          2  103397.25            
         1          2  103397.25            
         2          1 73058737.2            
         2          1 73058737.2            
         3          1   30711.94            
         3          1   30711.94            
         4          1  436414.01            
         4          1  436414.01
```

It isn't obvious why your rows appear to be duplicated. If you want both values to have the total difference as the calculation in your question shows - `(43801 + 43801) - (103397.25+103397.25)` - then you can just double the calculated difference:

```
  2 * (balance - lead(balance, 2)
    over (partition by serno order by accorder)) as diff

     SERNO   ACCORDER    BALANCE       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1      43801  -119192.5 
         1          1      43801  -119192.5 
         1          2  103397.25            
...
```

If the balance in each pair of rows might be different - so they aren't necessarily duplicates - then it would be a bit more complicated, but that doesn't seem to be the case.